# unable to see subnetworks for the given network in the GCP cloud composer Network configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create a Cloud Composer 2 in Google Cloud Platform. In the Network Configuration section, I chose a Network. But the Subnetwork doesn't display the list of subnetworks that are part of the Network. I tried to enter the subnet name also but it said it cannot find it. The default network does have the subnets in the VPC.

[image: 1]

How do I get the subnets?
I am expecting the subnets in the filter or I should be able to search with the name and load it.

Comment: could you confirm if you're the owner of the GCP project where you're trying to use the default network?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now, when trying to create a Compute instance. It seems like a bug in GCP as it comes and goes every few minutes. Tried in several regions. At one time, in the networks screen, the "default" subnet for one region was stuck in "overlapping error" but refreshing the page worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while creating vm instance, It looks like if vpc network is created in one region and creating vm instance in different region, this issue comes. After changing to same region, i was able to see the subnet.

there should be proper error message though.